# Guess the number in emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

This is the requirement of the problem

> The first player is asked from the keyboard for a decimal number from
> 0 to 9 without being displayed on the screen. The second player must
> guess the number that the first player thought of by entering it on
> the keyboard. After input, a message will always be printed indicating
> to the player if the number is too high, too low or the correct one.
> The player must enter numbers until he guesses the correct one. If the
> figure is correct, this is indicated and the game is stopped.
>
> Hint: see function 8 of INT 21h"

This is what I tried.. It works fine, but shows me double when the number is less "numarul este mic", and grater "numarul este mare", what should I do?

[image]

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data 
    prompt  db 'Introduceti o valoare intre 0 si 9:' ,0DH,0AH,'$'
    mesaj_1 db 'Numarul este mic'                    ,0DH,0AH,'$'
    mesaj_2 db 'Numarul este mare'                   ,0DH,0AH,'$'
    mesaj_3 db 'Numarul este corect!'                ,0DH,0AH,'$'
    mesaj_4 db 'Player introdu'                      ,0DH,0AH,'$'
    
.code

start:
   Mov ax, @data
   Mov ds, ax
   mov dx, offset mesaj_4
   
   mov ah, 9h
   int 21h
   
   mov ah, 8h
   int 21h
   
   mov cl, al
   
   mov dx, offset prompt
            
bucla:
   mov ah, 9h
   int 21h
   
   mov ah, 01h
   int 21h
   
   mov ch, al
   cmp ch, cl

   jl maiMic
   jg maiMare
   je corect
      
        
maiMic:
   mov dx, offset mesaj_1
   mov ah, 9h
   int 21h
   jl bucla
   
maiMare:
   mov dx, offset mesaj_2
   mov ah, 9h
   int 21h
   jmp bucla
      
corect:
   mov dx, offset mesaj_3
   mov ah, 9h
   int 21h 
   jmp tipareste
   
tipareste: 
   mov ah, 9
   int 21h
     
   mov ax, 4c00h
   int 21h
```

Comment: Single-step with the debugger built-in to emu8086 and follow the path of execution to see what happens.  `jl bucla` after `int 21h` returns is suspicious; I'm not sure it's guaranteed to preserve all the FLAGS.  (Although it probably will; `int` pushes FLAGS so a normal `iret` would restore them.)  Watch register values while this happens, especially after input calls to see which character got read.

Comment: Oh, you have a `mov ah, 9h` / `int 21h` at the top of `bucla:`, where you jump to with DX still set after printing it in either of the low/high blocks.  And again when you exit.  Don't put extra prints where you don't want them.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    mov dx, offset prompt
> bucla:
>    mov ah, 9h
>    int 21h
> ```

Your trouble with "double printing" comes from keeping this `mov dx, offset prompt` instruction outside of the loop. Like @Peter Cordes already noticed in a comment, each time the code jumps back to *bucla*, DX either points to *mesaj_1* or *mesaj_2*.

> ```
>    jmp tipareste
> tipareste: 
>    mov ah, 9
>    int 21h
> ```

Your trouble with "double printing" the final message is a simple matter of not repeating yourself.

---

I wrote next optimized version of your code. It is much shorter and jumps less around. And especially for

> ```
> jl maiMic
> jg maiMare
> je corect
> ```

it should be clear that the 3rd conditional jump is redundant. If the condition is neither *less* nor *greater*, then *equal* is the only case that remains. Re-arrange your code so it can fall through in the remaining case.

```
bucla:
  mov  dx, offset prompt
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h
  mov  ah, 01h
  int  21h
  mov  ch, al
  cmp  ch, cl
  mov  dx, offset mesaj_1
  jl   mesaj
  mov  dx, offset mesaj_2
  jg   mesaj
  mov  dx, offset mesaj_3
mesaj:
  mov  ah, 09h          ; Prints any of the 3 messages
  int  21h
  cmp  ch, cl
  jne  bucla            ; Repeat while not correct answer
  mov  ax, 4C00h
  int  21h
```